# Problem compiling MPI project, how do I get libopenmpi-dev on Fedora?

Tags: mpi, fedora, openmpi

I run

```
make
```

I get this error

```
mkdir -p build/
mpicc -Wall -fPIC -m64 -O3 -c src/main.c -o build/main.o
make: mpicc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:24: build/main.o] Error 127
```

while trying to compile an mpi project. This is for a project for school and we are "required" to download the libopenmpi-dev package for ubuntu. I'm on fedora so I've tried installing openmpi, mpich-devel, lib-openmpi-devel,libmpich but nothing works yet. I still get the same error. I'm not sure where to go from here.I thought it could just be an export error for mpicc but `locate mpicc` and `whereis mpicc` returns nothing.

Comment: Please use a code block and insert line breaks. It's unclear what you actually did.

Comment: Just did. sorry.

Comment: it is likely called `openmpi-devel`

Comment: You can look for packages that have `mpicc` as a file or directory with `dnf provides '*/mpicc'`.  N.B.: You need `*/` here or you need to know the full install path, which is unlikely since it's not installed.  You'll probably get multiple hits.  Try really hard to install the correct one.

Comment: Perhaps may help to build openmpi yourself - at least that's how I solved your same problem on Fedora

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to:

```
sudo dnf install openmpi openmpi-devel
```

See this for all other settings you need to make: https://brandonrozek.com/blog/openmpi-fedora/